Keycloak-Protected Routes Not Redirecting to Login in Express.js App
I am trying to set up auth in my express app using keycloak sso. I have exported the keycloak config from my client settings and add keycloak.protected to routes. However I am facing some issues

Even if the user is already logged in via sso, accessing the protected api routes (api/send-bulk-mail, /api/senders, /api/templates) doesn't return any data. These routes return only status code 302 Failed to load data: No content available because this request was redirected. 

If the user is not logged in, they are not being redirected to the keycloak login page as expected.

If I add protection before serving index.html, it gives an access denied error.


Here is my app.js code
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const client = require('@sendgrid/client')

require('dotenv').config()

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore()

const config = {
  realm: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
  'auth-server-url': process.env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER_URL,
  'ssl-required': 'external',
  resource: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT,
  'verify-token-audience': true,

  credentials: {
    secret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET,
  },
  'use-resource-role-mappings': true,
  'confidential-port': 0,
  'policy-enforcer': {
    credentials: {},
  },
}

const keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore }, config)

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
client.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
  }),
)

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore,
  }),
)
app.use(keycloak.middleware())

app.post('/api/send-bulk-email', keycloak.protect(), async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'ok', summary: [] })
})

app.get('/api/senders', keycloak.protect(), async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ senders: [] })
})

app.get('/api/templates', keycloak.protect(), async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ templates: [] })
})

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => `Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`)


Question
What could be causing the protected routes to not return the expected data even when authenticated and why is there no redirection to login page when not authenticated? How can I fix this to ensure that:

Authenticated users receive the correct data from protected routes.
Unauthenticated users are redirected to login page when trying to access protected routes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
